# Jquery Html5 game - Cannot read property of '1' undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Im creating a game with jquery and html canvas but i keep getting a error.
when the game is running only Zombie and SecondZombie move, the BossZombie stays still and i get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined on line 159
```

which is - if (Secondzombies[i][1] > player_y)

but that zombie moves fine its the boss that does not move (Which needs to move)

I have 3 enemies each created when the game starts and then updates via setInterval

my loop to update is as follows

```
function DrawZombies() { // Draw and update all zombies
for (var i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(zombie, zombies[i][0], zombies[i][1]);
}for (var i = 0; i < Secondzombies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(SecondZombie, Secondzombies[i][0], Secondzombies[i][1]);
}for (var i = 0; i < BossZombies.length; i++) {
    ctx.drawImage(BossZombie, BossZombies[i][0], BossZombies[i][1]);
}

// move Zombies
for (var i = 0; i < zombies.length; i++) 
{
    // zombies 1
    if (zombies[i][1] > player_y) { // move zombie towards player on the y axis
        zombies[i][1] -= zombies[i][4];
    } else {
        zombies[i][1] += zombies[i][4];
    } 

    if (zombies[i][0] > player_x) {
        zombies[i][0] -= zombies[i][4]; // move zombie towards player on the x axis
    } else {
        zombies[i][0] += zombies[i][4];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; Secondzombies.length; i++)
{
    // zombies 2
    if (Secondzombies[i][1] > player_y) { // move zombie towards player on the y axis
        Secondzombies[i][1] -= Secondzombies[i][4];
    } else {
        Secondzombies[i][1] += Secondzombies[i][4];
    } 

    if (Secondzombies[i][0] > player_x) {
        Secondzombies[i][0] -= Secondzombies[i][4]; // move zombie towards player on the x axis
    } else {
        Secondzombies[i][0] += Secondzombies[i][4];
    }
}

for (var i = 0; BossZombies.length; i++)
    {
    // zombies 3
    if (BossZombies[i][1] > player_y) { // move zombie towards player on the y axis
        BossZombies[i][1] -= BossZombies[i][4];
    } else {
        BossZombies[i][1] += BossZombies[i][4];
    } 

    if (BossZombies[i][0] > player_x) {
        BossZombies[i][0] -= BossZombies[i][4]; // move zombie towards player on the x axis
    } else {
        BossZombies[i][0] += BossZombies[i][4];
    }
}
}
```

each zombie is created as follows

```
for (var i = 0; i < zombie_total; i++) {
    var TypeOfZombie = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); // generate random number for type of zombie
    if (TypeOfZombie <= 4) { // create type one zombie
        zombies.push([Math.round(Math.random()*(width-20)/1), Math.round(Math.random()*(height-250)/1), zombie_width, zombie_height, zombie_speed]);
        zombie_x += zombie_width + 50;

    } else if (TypeOfZombie == 5) { 
        Secondzombies.push([Math.round(Math.random()*(width-20)/1), Math.round(Math.random()*(height-250)/1), Secondzombie_width, Secondzombie_height, Secondzombie_speed]);
        Secondzombie_x += Secondzombie_width + 50;
    } else { // leaves only a 6 generated so generate boss
        BossZombies.push([Math.round(Math.random()*(width-20)/1), Math.round(Math.random()*(height-250)/1), BossZombie_width, BossZombie_height, BossZombie_speed]);
        BossZombie_x += BossZombie_width + 50;
    }
}
```

I will add that all zombies are draw but only zombies & SecondZombies move and BossZombie stays still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though it's your for() loops that are the problem.

take a look at this line, for instance

```
for (var i = 0; Secondzombies.length; i++)
```

This will run through all items in Secondzombies, but it won't terminate correctly (i.e. it'll overrun the array) because the condition "Secondzombies.length" will always evaluate to 'true'

perhaps replace that (and the Bosszombies loop) with

```
for (var i = 0; i < Secondzombies.length; i++)
```

Comment: Cannot believe i missed that, thank you very much was driving me nuts trying to figure it out

Comment: My pleasure. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes.